# Shell does not show home(first) view in SAPUI5 when using Router

Tags: shell, router, sapui5

I am using Shell in my SAPUI5 application, like this:

```
var oShell = new sap.ui.ux3.Shell("myShell", {
            showLogoutButton: false,
            showTools:false,
            showPane: false,
            headerType:sap.ui.ux3.ShellHeaderType.SlimNavigation,
            worksetBar:false,

            //Add header items 
            headerItems:[sap.ui.view("login",{type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS, viewName:"prototype.login"})],

            //Add navigation items
            worksetItems:[
                    new sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem("home", {key:"home",text:"Majas"}), 
                    new sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem("news", {key:"news",text:"Jaunumi"}),
                    new sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem("results", {key:"results",text:"Rezultati"}),
                    new sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem("team", {key:"teams",text:"Komanda"}),                         
                    new sap.ui.ux3.NavigationItem("gallery", {key:"gallery",text:"Galerija"})                  
            ],

            worksetItemSelected:function (oEvent) {
                var sSelected = oEvent.getParameter("id"),
                oHashChanger = sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.getInstance();   
                oHashChanger.setHash(oRouter.getURL("_" + sSelected))
        },

        });
```

Then I am using Router to set URL adresses to views represented in Shell, like this:

```
var oRouter = new sap.ui.core.routing.Router([  {
            pattern: "home",
            name: "_home",
            view: "prototype.home",
            viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
            targetControl: "myShell",
            targetAggregation: "content",
            clearTarget: true,              
            fireEvent: function() {
                oShell.setSelectedWorksetItem("home");
            }

        },  
        //Adding URL to "news" view
        { 
            pattern: "news",
            name: "_news",
            view: "prototype.news",
            viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
            targetControl: "myShell",
            targetAggregation: "content",
            clearTarget: true,
            callback: function(oRoute, oArguments) {
                oShell.setSelectedWorksetItem("news");
            }
        },

        {
            pattern: "results",
            name: "_results",
            view: "prototype.resultsVirsliga",
            viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
            targetControl: "myShell",
            targetAggregation: "content",
            clearTarget: true,
            callback: function(oRoute, oArguments) {
                oShell.setSelectedWorksetItem("results");
            }
        },

        {
            pattern: "team",
            name: "_team",
            view: "prototype.team",
            viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
            targetControl: "myShell",
            targetAggregation: "content",
            clearTarget: true,
            callback: function(oRoute, oArguments) {
                oShell.setSelectedWorksetItem("team");
            }
        },

        {
            pattern: "image",
            name: "_gallery",
            view: "prototype.image",
            viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
            targetControl: "myShell",
            targetAggregation: "content",
            clearTarget: true,
            callback: function(oRoute, oArguments) {
                oShell.setSelectedWorksetItem("gallery");
            }
        },

        {
            pattern: "login",
            name: "_login",
            view: "prototype.login",
            viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
            targetControl: "myShell",
            targetAggregation: "content",
            clearTarget: true,
            callback: function(oRoute, oArguments) {
                oShell.setSelectedHeaderItem("login");
            }
        }
    ]);
    oRouter.initialize();
```

Everything works fine, except first(home view), when I open my application (home view) it shows blank page, only navigation is visible, then I navigate to other page and then back to home page an everything appears and then works fine. 
Why view does not load when I enter the page, but only when I navigate to other view and then back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For home view to load by default in your router define it as below with pattern space.

```js
 pattern: "",
   name: "_home",
   view: "prototype.home",
   viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
   targetControl: "myShell",
   targetAggregation: "content",
   clearTarget: true,
   fireEvent: function() {
     oShell.setSelectedWorksetItem("home");
   }
```

Though it is an old question but it may help somebody in future as it helped me to resolve the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the Shell, set also the `content` parameter with the `home` view.

Like this:

```
...
content: [sap.ui.view("home",{type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS, viewName:"prototype.home"})]
...
```

Comment: I have tried this, but then I got an error(adding element with duplicate id "home"), because I use the same view (home view) as NavigationItem and in content. How to solve this?

Comment: This means that the declaration of the `home` view is performed twice. Try to just call the `home` view in the `content` instead of declaring it. Like this `content: [home]`, or `content: [sap.ui.jsview("prototype.home")]`.
Let me know if it works...

Comment: Unfortunatley it does not work, error is the same - Duplicate ID.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern: "" for home view did the trick!